# how can i replace one value from list object and same new value assign to same object list using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var test = list contains 10 rows with 4 columns;

test.then(function(d)){
    $scope.mylist = d.data;
}
```

example:my list contains one row like

```
name:"rajesh";
id:10009;
branch:"dotnet";etc...
```

here i want to replace branch dotnet to angular for all rows and again that value assign same to same object.

means i need output like this?

```
name:"rajesh";//1st row
id:100009;
branch:"angular";


name:"sai";//2nd row
id:1004;
branch:"angular";  like this
```

please suggest i am new to angularjs

Answer (score 0):

FYI, You are using very old JavaScript syntax. (Recommended to upgrade)
Anyways, extending the code snippet in your question.

#### Update

question is different from what you are asking in comments. if you are looking for code to get it done. Here it is...

```
        const results = [
            { Name: 'raju', Id: 1009, Branch: 'cse' },
            { Name: 'sai', Id: 1019, Branch: 'ece' },
            { Name: 'nandu', Id: 1089, Branch: 'civil' }
        ];

        const output = results.map(user => {
            user.Name = '****';
            return user;
        });
```

Just use `map` to transform your data.

```
var test = list contains 10 rows with 4 columns;

test.then(function(d)){

    $scope.mylist = d.data.map(function(user) {
        if (user.branch === 'dotnet') {
            user.branch = 'angular';
        }
        return user;
    });    
}
```

Comment: var results= [   {        Name: "raju",        Id: 1009,        Branch: "cse"      
    },
    {        Name: "sai"     Id: 1019,Branch: "ece"
        
    },
    {
         Name: "nandu",
        Id: 1089,
        Branch: "civil"
    }
]    now i need to replace name columns with ***** means i need output like this.var results= [
    {
        Name: "*****",
        Id: 1009,
        Branch: "cse"
    },
    {
        Name: "*****",
        Id: 1019,
        Branch: "ece"
    },
    {
         Name: "*****",
        Id: 1089,
        Branch: "civil"
    }
]